# modal doesnt work on android phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I uploaded my website to the internet but it seems the modal does not work properly on android phones. It works great on computers but mobile? not so much

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Sign up as an Jobseeker</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign up as an Employer</button>
<!-- Modal:Jobseeker -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Finalization</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Hello! Please add some additional information to finish the Sign up process.</p>
            <i class="icon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is required to receive notifications from the system."></i>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="cellno" placeholder="Cellphone Number e.g 63905XXXXXXX"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="register2" value="Finish" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
<!-- End of Modal:Jobseeker -->
```

Please help

Comment: what's not working properly in modal on mobile devices?

Comment: You can also place your website link here so that we can open it and see how it actually looks.